# Mapping election's data with google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to map the results of the last **Venezuelan president elections** in a Google geoMap chart.

I'm trying to put in the same chart the results of both mayor candidates, but it seems Google Chart is unable to do it.

I'm trying to reproduce the example showed at [Google Code Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#geo_map)
using options as `options['region'] = 'VE';` to set the limit map to my country and the  [ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2%3aVE) city codes for my region, but stil unable to show two sets of data on the same map. this is the [Data](http://www.eleccionesvenezuela.com/noticia-mapa-politico-electoral-venezuela-14-abril-594.html) i'm using.

a sample data would be:

```
    function drawVisualization() {
  var data_candidate_a = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Ciudad', 'Result','Label'],
            ['VE-A', 200,'CARACAS'],
            ['VE-B', 300,'AMAZONAS'],
            ['VE-C', 400,'BOLIVAR'],
            ['VE-C', 500,'BARINAS'],
            ['VE-D', 600,'ANZOATEGUI'],
            ['VE-E', 700,'MIRANDA']
          ]);

   var data_candidate_b = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Ciudad', 'Result','Label'],
                ['VE-A', 100,'CARACAS'],
                ['VE-B', 150,'AMAZONAS'],
                ['VE-C', 200,'BOLIVAR'],
                ['VE-C', 600,'BARINAS'],
                ['VE-D', 300,'ANZOATEGUI'],
                ['VE-E', 800,'MIRANDA']
              ]);

  var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  var options = {};
  options["region"] = "VE";
  geomap.draw(data_candidate_a, options);
}
```

Comment: Try setting `resolution: 'provinces'` in your options.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1:** You cannot have a 'label' column on your chart -- google doesn't like it.

**Solution #1:** Use the `{v: 'value', f: 'format'}` trick to show the city name on mouseover (your column C labels).

**Issue #2:** You aren't showing state-level boundaries.

**Solution #2:** You need to add an option for `resolution: 'provinces'`

I have recreated a working version of your chart below (using GeoChart rather than GeoMap, it will likely work for GeoMap too, but GeoChart is generally more accessible because it doesn't use flash):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Ciudad');
  data.addColumn('number', 'result');
  data.addRows([
    [{v: 'VE-A', f: 'CARACAS'}, 200],
    [{v: 'VE-B', f: 'AMAZONAS'}, 300],
    [{v: 'VE-C', f: 'BOLIVAR'}, 400],
    [{v: 'VE-C', f: 'BARINAS'}, 500],
    [{v: 'VE-D', f: 'ANZOATEGUI'}, 600],
    [{v: 'VE-E', f: 'MIRANDA'}, 700]
  ]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));

  var options = {
    region: "VE",
    resolution: "provinces"
  };

  geochart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it actualy works with the datatable i set. What I want to do is to merge both datasets into one map. Thanks for you help.

Comment: btw, thanks on your recommendation about using geoChart, i'm changing the code now to give it a try.

Comment: You can't mix two sets of data on one map. How would you expect it to show? It isn't possible.

Comment: I'd like to show both markers separately, each state showing two colored circles.

Comment: I already managed to show both result in one marker, but the circle shows the sum of it.

Comment: you want markers not regions? That's a totally different story! Are you looking for cities not states? Perhaps you could edit your question to make it a bit more clear...